# How to replace whole characters in a string as same characters in c#?

Tags: c#, string

Example:

```
string input = "super";
string rep = "a";
```

I want the output same charterers as per given input `string` `length`. The output should be "`aaaaa`".
I dont like to use own FOR or While loops logic, is there any alternatives to accomplish it.

Comment: Is this even a question? You could start with looping using a string builder to so many other ways. Do some research before you ask a question. And do post as to what have you tried before expecting other people to answer.

Comment: Fine @ Shakti Prakash Singh. Questions never will come without a proper reason. Please see the Answer section have you tried ever? and I am looking the optimized way to achieve this from the answers.

Comment: 1) You did not mention as to what you have tried. 2) You did not mention that you are looking to optimize the action. Please be clear with your questions. And do let others know what "you" have tried. Don't ask me what I have tried or not. I am not the one who is asking a question here. You are just wasting other people's time by asking questions without your proper research.

Comment: 1) My question is clear so no need additional info. 2) As per your first comment, you suggested to use Loop logic, I agreed but that one is normal we can able to do. But in the answers of others says better way than own LOOP logic thats what I need. I agreed this very simple question (not :)) in your view and cool... :)

Comment: If you do not understand @ShaktiPrakashSingh's comment, read StackOverflow's How to Ask guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask (specifically, "Do your homework")

Comment: @luiscubal - Thanks. I gave up on him. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I have added some more text in the question and still is any issue I remove the question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**By Using Regular Expressions**

```
string input = "123";
string rep = "Abc";
string output = Regex.Replace(input , "(.)", rep)
```

**By using LINQ**

```
string output = string.Concat(input.Select(c => rep));
```

**Output**

> AbcAbcAbc

Comment: I guess it is unnecessary to capture match of `.`

Comment: @Gowtham don't guess. tell the reason why?

Answer (score 27):

Use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx)

```
string output = new string('a', input.Length);
```

If you want to repeat a real `string` n-times, you could use `Enumerable.Repeat`:

```
string output = string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(rep, input.Length));
```

I use `String.Join` to concatenate each string with a specified seperator(in this case none).

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here is another way:

```
new string(input.Select(c => 'a').ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

another way :

```
string input = "super";
string rep = "a";
var newStr = input.Select(x => rep);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of if you want a solution that's way to big but very easy to understand:

```
string output = "";
foreach(char a in input) {    // == for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    output += rep;
}
```

I didn't know about working with the constructor.
It's a very easy solution, but it'll only work with char's. So you can't repeat strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
string op = "";
for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
   op += rep;
```